# iOS and Swift: Ok to force unwrap tableView.indexPath?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, optional-values

I have a segue from a table view controller to another view controller. Inside the method prepare(for: sender) I need to get the indexPath of the cell that triggered the segue. Is it Ok to force unwrap the index path in this case? After all the prepare() method was triggered by tapping on a table row so it seems I can make the assumption that 'sender' contains a reference to a valid object yes?

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {   
  if segue.identifier == "TheCorrectSegue" {   
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell)! <-- is this OK?   
}}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the segue is connected to the table view cell it's safe because always a valid cell is passed thru the `sender` parameter.

But it's actually not more code to write

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {   
    guard segue.identifier == "TheCorrectSegue", let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell, 
      let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return } 
      // do something with the index path
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may seem like a bit of over-engineering, but I have table views that had buttons in the cell and/or allowed the cell to be selected directly.

So I created UIView extension methods to get table view stuff.

```
extension UIView {

    var superTableViewCell: UITableViewCell? {
        if let cell = self as? UITableViewCell {
            return cell
        }

        return superview?.superTableViewCell
    }

    var superTableView: UITableView? {
        if let tableView = self as? UITableView {
            return tableView
        }

        return superview?.superTableView
    }

    var indexPathOfSuperTableViewCell: IndexPath? {
        if let tableView = superTableView, let cell = superTableViewCell {
            return tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
        }

        return nil
    }

}
```

This allowed me to reduce the problem of getting the correct index path to

```
private func _segueIndexPath(for view: UIView?) -> IndexPath? {
    if let indexPath = view?.indexPathOfSuperTableViewCell {
        return indexPath
    }

    return tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
}
```

and then finally,

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.identifier ?? "" {
    case "TheCorrectSegue":
        guard let indexPath = _segueIndexPath(for: sender as? UIView) else {
            // Handle error
            return
        }

        // prepare for the segue.

    default:
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    }
}
```

Comment: After thinking about my question I realize the deeper question I was trying to ask was this:  Can I assume iOS will give me valid parameters when prepare() is called or do I always need to guard against situations that should never really happen?  In your code above I wonder what you would do in the guard statement else clause?  How would you handle such an error other than crashing?